# what would be a suitable rest api framework (c++) for my use case?

Tags: c++, rest, docker, health-monitoring

I have reused some C code (gcc compiler), which is running inside docker container under ubuntu. So, I want to add some REST APIs like health check and readiness check. Do you know any C++ REST API frameworks. I checked this side: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs but too many frameworks ;)

I use the C code for mqtt communication. It means the docker container subscribe or publish some messages. The REST API should only be used for the both checks. I want to check if the container is alive and is working properly but the main task is communication via mqtt and calculation of algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some REST frameworks at [this link](https://github.com/fffaraz/awesome-cpp#networking).
For example [Restbed](https://github.com/corvusoft/restbed) - C++11 Asynchronous RESTful lightweight framework. [AGPL]

Comment: dzieki Szymon ;)

Comment: ups, this is a client, what about server? because i have to provide these APIs ;)

Comment: @user3930618 Ok so you need to [Restbed](https://github.com/corvusoft/restbed) - C++11 Asynchronous RESTful lightweight framework. [AGPL]